# Sentinel-2 topographic artifacts: How to fix?

Tags: sentinel-2, topography

I'm working with Sentinel-2 (Level2A) false color composite images. A few of them present artifacts in alpine terrain. See highlighted area on the image below, in the Swiss Alps.
These artifacts are present on the side of the mountain that is in the shade due to the sun angle. There are grey-ish areas that probalby come from a wrong satellite image processing step between the shadows (black) and the glaciers (white). You can see that in these areas, all information is lost.

My questions are: Is that normal artifacts in mountain areas? Is there a way to get a correct image in these areas by applying some filters on the raw S2 data (like a shadow mask, a re-classification of image classes, ...).

[image: Glacier situated in the Swiss Alps]

Comment: Could you specify what you think should by filtered in your image ?

Comment: Hi, I outlined the area in the image that looks wrong and I specified my question above